# 特定のフレームをキャプチャし使用したい

Tags: python, opencv

ある動画のフレームを読み込んでROIを囲み、トラッキングするコードを作っています。

その際１フレーム目ではなく、〇フレーム目といったように好きなフレームをキャプチャしたいと思っていますがどのように改変すればよいでしょうか？どなたかご教授お願い致します。

```
import cv2

   # KCF
tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()

 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r"C:\Users\****\OneDrive\デスクトップ\MYpython\sample_speed3.mp4")



while True:
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       if not ret:
           continue
       bbox = (0,0,10,10)
       bbox = cv2.selectROI(frame, False)
       ok = tracker.init(frame, bbox)
       cv2.destroyAllWindows()
       break

while True:
       # VideoCaptureから1フレーム読み込む
       ret, frame = cap.read()
       
       if not ret:
           k = cv2.waitKey(1)
           if k == 27 :
               break
           continue

       # Start timer
       timer = cv2.getTickCount()

       # トラッカーをアップデートする
       track, bbox = tracker.update(frame)

       # FPSを計算する
       fps = cv2.getTickFrequency() / (cv2.getTickCount() - timer);

       # 検出した場所に四角を書く
       if track:
           # Tracking success
           p1 = (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1]))
           p2 = (int(bbox[0] + bbox[2]), int(bbox[1] + bbox[3]))
           cv2.rectangle(frame, p1, p2, (0,255,0), 2, 1)
           
       else :
           # トラッキングが外れたら警告を表示する
           cv2.putText(frame, "Failure", (10,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA);


       # FPSを表示する
       cv2.putText(frame, "FPS : " + str(int(fps)), (10,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,255,0), 1, cv2.LINE_AA);

       # 加工済の画像を表示する
       cv2.imshow("Tracking", frame)

       # キー入力を1ms待って、k が27（ESC）だったらBreakする
       k = cv2.waitKey(1)
       if k == 27 :
           break



while True:
   ret, frame = cap.read()                                         

   # フレームが取得できない場合はループを抜ける
   if not ret:
       break
# キャプチャをリリースして、ウィンドウをすべて閉じる
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()



print(p1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, フレーム数)
```

を用いることによって任意のフレームまで進めるようです。

参考リンク
・[https://note.nkmk.me/python-opencv-videocapture-file-camera/](https://note.nkmk.me/python-opencv-videocapture-file-camera/#:%7E:text=%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%E4%BD%8D%E7%BD%AE%E3%82%92%E4%BB%BB%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AB%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%E3%81%AFset()%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%86%E3%80%82)
・[https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/opencv-videocapture-mp4-movie-py/](https://algorithm.joho.info/programming/python/opencv-videocapture-mp4-movie-py/#:%7E:text=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9F%E3%80%81%E5%8F%96%E5%BE%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%83%95%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%81%AE%E7%8F%BE%E5%9C%A8%E4%BD%8D%E7%BD%AE%E3%82%92%E4%BB%BB%E6%84%8F%E3%81%AB%E7%A7%BB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%82%82%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%80%82)

Answer (score 0):

コードを以下のように追加することで解決しました。
ご協力ありがとうございました。

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("con1.mp4")
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 3000)
```